# GWT AnchorElement scroll within an overflowed FlowPanel

Tags: java, gwt

I have a list of Anchors that should scroll when clicked, using the traditional `<a href="#anchorName">` and within a flow panel panel I have the list of sections such as `<div id="anchorName">Name</div>`. Finally, all this resides on a dialog box. I'm having an issue where if the page content, not the dialog box content but the page itself, is large and enables the scrollbar. When the anchor is clicked, it causes the entire page to scroll.

Is there a better way to do this?